# Youcompleteme stopped working in debian unstable

Tags: python, vim, debian, youcompleteme

After updating vim-nox from 8.0.0095-1 to 8.0.0134-1 and some python packages youcompleteme stopped working and throws errors whenever I start vim.

### Output of YcmDebugInfo:

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
Error detected while processing function <SNR>39_DebugInfo[2]..<SNR>39_Pyeval:
line    4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 550, in DebugInfo
    'debug_info' )
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 81, in PostDataToHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 174, in JsonFromFuture
    _ValidateResponseObject( response )
  File "/usr/share/vim-youcompleteme/python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 203, in _ValidateResponseObject
their_hmac = ToBytes( b64decode( response.headers[ _HMAC_HEADER ] ) )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'x-ycm-hmac'
E858: Eval did not return a valid python object
```

It looks like the communication between ycmd and the vim counterpart youcompleteme is not working correctly anymore. vim8 in debian unstable uses python 3 while ycmd is started with python 2.7. The package versions of ycmd and youcompleteme are matching and did not change recently (it was working with the same versions).
Does someone have youcompleteme working with a recent update in debian unstable?

Comment: [Same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41510573/660921) here. Probably shouldn't mark this as a dupe though since the other question is pretty low quality.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Ubuntu machine. Solved it by installing YCM from source, so this might work for you, too. But the best long-term solution would be to post a bug report to Debian, since their package is broken while the newest upstream source is not. (The maintainer might likely not notice this question.)